# Rails migration and column change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

working with sqlite3 for local dev.  Prod DB is MySql.

Have a migration file for a column change.

```
class ChangeDateToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column(:orders, :closed_date, :datetime)
  end

  def self.down
    change_column(:orders, :closed_date, :date)
  end
end
```

Errors out saying `index name 'temp_index_altered_orders_on_closed_location_id_and_parent_company_id' on table 'altered_orders' is too long; the limit is 64 characters`

Know there is a limitation on index name with sqlite, but is there a workaround for this?

EDIT 
Workaround I used.

```
class ChangeDateToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_index(:orders, [:closed_location_id, :parent_company_id])
    change_column(:orders, :closed_date, :datetime)
    add_index(:orders, [:closed_location_id, :parent_company_id], :name => "add_index_to_orders_cli_pci")
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index(:orders, :name => "add_index_to_orders_cli_pci")
    change_column(:orders, :closed_date, :date)
    add_index(:orders, [:closed_location_id, :parent_company_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like my production and development environments to match as much as possible.  Its helps avoid gotchas.  If I were deploying MySQL I would run my development environment with MySQL too.  Besides, I am also not super familiar with SQLite so this approach appeals to my lazy side - I only need to know the ins and outs of one db.

Answer (score 0):

You could hack your copy of active record; Add the following

```
          opts[:name] = opts[:name][0..63] # can't be more than 64 chars long
```

Around line 535 (in version 3.2.9) of $GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb

It's a hack but it might get you past a hurdle. If I had more time, I'd look in to writing a test and sending a pull request to rails core team.